# Android time format compare

Tags: java

How do I compare a string time like "18:45" with the current system time?
I am using:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.US);
String time2 = "18:45";
long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date date1 = new Date(dtMili); //current system time
Date date2 = sdf.parse(time2);
if (date2.after(date1)) {
    //bingo!
}
```

Debugging values--I found `date1` as current system datetime and `date2` as `"January 1970 - 18:45"`

I need to compare only times, the date must be same.

Comment: There is no date information in your input string. It looks like hour and minute. Do you need to see if currently it's 18:45 (for that input)? "the date must be same" does not make sense.

Comment: 18:45 is a example, it comes from a webservice, I need to check if this specific time is after or below current time. It is not necessary use date.

Comment: if(TimeStr1.CompareTo(TimeStr2) > 0) resolves!!!!